# How do I remove a JS file for Mobile Safari using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, ipad, mobile-safari

One of the Javascript files on my site is screwing up the display on iPad (Mobile Safari). I want to remove the file only on an iPad and serve it for every other browser.

I've got the following javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<![CDATA[
function removejscssfile(filename, filetype){
 var targetelement=(filetype=="js")? "script" : (filetype=="css")? "link" : "none" //determine element type to create nodelist from
 var targetattr=(filetype=="js")? "src" : (filetype=="css")? "href" : "none" //determine corresponding attribute to test for
 var allsuspects=document.getElementsByTagName(targetelement)
 for (var i=allsuspects.length; i>=0; i--){ //search backwards within nodelist for matching elements to remove
  if (allsuspects[i] && allsuspects[i].getAttribute(targetattr)!=null && allsuspects[i].getAttribute(targetattr).indexOf(filename)!=-1)
   allsuspects[i].parentNode.removeChild(allsuspects[i]) //remove element by calling parentNode.removeChild()
 }
}

if((navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i)) 
{
  removejscssfile("somescript.js", "js") //remove all occurences of "somescript.js" on page for ipad 
}
]]
</script>
```

Firstly - is the above Javascript valid? (I have a limited knowledge)

Secondly - is this the best way to do it?

Comment: That won't help; the code will already have executed.

Comment: That definitely answers the first question - cheers

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't using php or something else where this is a lot easier, you should do it the other way around, where you conditionally load the files into the head of the document, if the browser isn't an ipad.

```
    function loadjscssfile(filename, filetype) {
            if (filetype == "js") { //if filename is a external JavaScript file

                var fileref = document.createElement('script')
                fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript")
                fileref.setAttribute("src", filename)

            }
            else if (filetype == "css") { //if filename is an external CSS file
                var fileref = document.createElement("link")
                fileref.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet")
                fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/css")
                fileref.setAttribute("href", filename)
            }
            if (typeof fileref != "undefined")
                document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref)
    }

    var isiPad = navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i) != null;

    if (!isiPad) {
        //load js OR css files
    }
```

Comment: Argh - the whole thing seems like quite an inelegant solution (on my part). If possible I don't want to have to conditionally load all my js files for the site. The developer browser debugging tools for iOS are positively awful. Thanks for your input Cartuzzi - much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by finding the offending JS function and adding:

```
&& navigator.userAgent.match(/ipad/i) == null
```

Simple is good